# i get this Error: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not File when call file on db

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i made sqlalchemy db and upload cs file.
but when i try to call fie that inside the db its alwayd show this error

Error: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not File

is there any option to change file query into file path?
if i change with open(my_data, newline='') as f:
to
with open("augut.csv", newline='') as f: its work. but i want to call file that already store in db.

'''

```
@app.route("/proses/<id>/", methods=["GET"])

def proses(id):
    my_data = File.query.get(id)
    with open(my_data, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        data = list(reader)
    transactions = data
    patterns = pyfpgrowth.find_frequent_patterns(transactions, len(transactions) * 20/100)
    rules = pyfpgrowth.generate_association_rules(patterns, 0.5)
    return str(rules)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

The call to `File.query.get(id)` return a `File` instance. You need to get the file name from `my_data` and use it with `open`

Assuming you have something like:

```
class File(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  Column(String(50))
```

the call to `my_data.name` will return the file name

Comment: 1) share your File class 2)  keep using `File.query.get(id)` that will return an instance of File.

Comment: i gt this error instead FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'april.csv'

Comment: it means that you need to keep the file in DB using full path:  Example: `/files/april.csv`. Anyway - this problem in not related to your original question.

Comment: yes it has no error when i move the csv file in the same folder as the python folder

Comment: can you give me example to keep file in db using full path?

Comment: Instead of just adding the file name `april.csv` , use the full path when the dile is added to DB - `/files/april.csv` (as an example)

Comment: how to use full path on db?

Comment: `@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])def upload():
 if request.method == "POST":

  if request.files:
   file = request.files['inputFile']
   newFile = File(name=file.filename, data=file.read())
 db.session.add(newFile)
 db.session.commit()`

Comment: Assuming the csv files are in the current folder as the python files ( which is not a good idea ), concatenate the cwd ( current working directory ) to the file name before you save it to db

Comment: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-os-getcwd-chdir/#:~:text=Get%20the%20current%20working%20direcory%3A%20os.,-getcwd()&text=getcwd()%20returns%20the%20absolute,the%20result%20with%20print()%20.&text=getcwd%20stands%20for%20%22get%20current%20working%20directory%22.